# Getting sequential output from multiple threads in python script

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multithreaded script that runs [*mtr*](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/), a traceroute-like network diagnostic tool, against IP addresses given in arguments and uses the MaxMind GeoIP database to look up the location of IPs in *mtr*'s output.

Using my script I am getting mixed output as all the threads are writing to the same STDOUT at the same time.
I don't want to use locks as it slows down the execution speed of the script.

Below is my script (Geo_MTR_Final.py):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import threading
from Queue import Queue
import geoip2.database
import geoip2.errors
import argparse
import logging
import re
from termcolor import colored
import time


queue = Queue()
FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-7s) %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT,)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars="-+")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dest", help="Destination IP Addresses", action="append", dest="ipd", default=[])
args = parser.parse_args()


def check_geo_country(ip):
    try:
        reader_country = geoip2.database.Reader('xxx')
        response_country = reader_country.country(ip)
        mycountry = response_country.country.name
        reader_country.close()
        return mycountry
    except (geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError, ValueError):
        pass


def check_geo_city(ip):
    try:
        reader_city = geoip2.database.Reader('xxx')
        response_city = reader_city.city(ip)
        mycity = response_city.city.name
        reader_city.close()
        return mycity
    except (geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError, ValueError):
        pass


def yoyo(q):
    while True:
        myip = q.get()
        logging.info('Started')
        cmd = "mtr --no-dns -rwc 10 %s" % myip
        op = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
        for line in op.split("\n"):
            ip_mtr = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
            if ip_mtr:
                ip_final = ''.join(ip_mtr)
                ctry = check_geo_country(ip_final)
                cty = check_geo_city(ip_final)
                country = colored(ctry, 'yellow', attrs=['bold'])
                city = colored(cty, 'magenta', attrs=['bold'])
                print "%s----{ %s }----{ %s }" % (line, country, city)
            else:
                print "%s" % line
        q.task_done()


num_of_threads = len(args.ipd)

for num in range(num_of_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=yoyo, args=(queue,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

for arguments in args.ipd:
    queue.put(arguments)

queue.join()
print "Done"
```

The command i am using is:-

```
root@L-ubuntu:# python Geo_MTR_Final.py -d 216.58.199.164 -d 106.10.138.240 -d 31.13.79.220 -d 216.58.199.174
```

The output i am getting is:-

```
[INFO] (Thread-3) Started
[INFO] (Thread-2) Started
[INFO] (Thread-1) Started
[INFO] (Thread-4) Started

Start: Tue Apr 26 13:37:23 2016
HOST: L-ubuntu       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 10.37.144.254  40.0%    10  106.8  63.6   5.9 125.4  53.2----{ None }----{ None }
  2.|-- 182.75.202.145  0.0%    10   43.3  14.7   3.4  54.2  18.5----{ India }----{ None }
  3.|-- 182.79.245.185  0.0%    10  172.4 129.7  95.3 188.6  31.7----{ India }----{ None }
  4.|-- 103.4.97.138    0.0%    10   82.8 109.4  80.7 272.5  58.8----{ Singapore }----{ None }
  5.|-- 173.252.65.188  0.0%    10  173.9 101.7  78.2 173.9  29.6----{ United States }----{ Menlo Park }
Start: Tue Apr 26 13:37:23 2016
HOST: L-ubuntu       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
Start: Tue Apr 26 13:37:23 2016
HOST: L-ubuntu       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
Start: Tue Apr 26 13:37:23 2016
HOST: L-ubuntu       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 10.37.144.254  50.0%    10    6.1  11.9   2.8  20.5   7.3----{ None }----{ None }
  6.|-- 173.252.66.16  20.0%    10  108.5  91.9  80.6 108.5   9.0----{ United States }----{ Menlo Park }
  1.|-- 10.37.144.254  50.0%    10    5.3  16.7   2.8  34.5  12.9----{ None }----{ None }
  1.|-- 10.37.144.254  50.0%    10    5.3  10.2   3.2  18.5   6.1----{ None }----{ None }
  2.|-- 182.75.202.145  0.0%    10   39.2  44.5   4.8 279.5  84.0----{ India }----{ None }
  2.|-- 182.75.202.145  0.0%    10   34.7  38.7   3.0 274.8  83.8----{ India }----{ None }
  2.|-- 182.75.202.145  0.0%    10   35.4  39.3   3.5 270.8  82.1----{ India }----{ None }
  7.|-- 31.13.79.220    0.0%    10  117.4 114.3  90.4 163.5  27.2----{ Ireland }----{ None }

  3.|-- 182.79.224.77   0.0%    10   14.9  30.4   8.5 167.1  48.5----{ India }----{ None }
  3.|-- 182.79.245.66   0.0%    10  101.0 127.9  93.4 270.8  53.5----{ India }----{ None }
  3.|-- 182.79.255.105  0.0%    10   14.7  29.9   8.6 165.8  48.2----{ India }----{ None }
  4.|-- 27.111.228.131 20.0%    10  347.9 287.3 257.4 347.9  29.5----{ Singapore }----{ Ayer Raja New Town }
  4.|-- 72.14.205.93    0.0%    10  132.4  76.1  42.6 132.4  30.5----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  4.|-- 72.14.205.93    0.0%    10  132.6  73.4  44.8 132.6  29.7----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  5.|-- 203.84.209.77   0.0%    10  139.6 128.3 106.8 181.4  22.4----{ Hong Kong }----{ None }
  5.|-- 66.249.95.106   0.0%    10   61.6  72.2  51.4 136.3  26.5----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  6.|-- 106.10.128.7    0.0%    10  183.2 112.8  89.5 183.2  36.4----{ Singapore }----{ None }
   5.|-- 66.249.95.106   0.0%    10   58.6  79.0  51.8 136.2  30.2----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  6.|-- 209.85.142.129  0.0%    10  167.1  86.0  58.1 167.1  31.9----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  7.|-- 106.10.128.17   0.0%    10  117.4 120.3  88.8 286.2  60.0----{ Singapore }----{ None }
  6.|-- 209.85.142.129  0.0%    10  155.3  86.4  62.5 155.3  27.5----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  7.|-- 72.14.239.25    0.0%    10  101.8  95.8  62.6 266.7  61.2----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  8.|-- 106.10.128.71   0.0%    10  101.7 135.5  89.9 242.2  52.2----{ Singapore }----{ None }
  7.|-- 72.14.239.25    0.0%    10  103.0  93.3  63.5 257.8  59.1----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  8.|-- 209.85.143.5    0.0%    10   84.6 113.1  69.1 200.2  47.8----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }
  9.|-- 106.10.138.240  0.0%    10  111.8 109.9  92.7 126.9  14.2----{ Singapore }----{ None }
   8.|-- 209.85.143.5    0.0%    10   83.6 104.7  70.3 196.2  47.0----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }

  9.|-- 216.58.199.164  0.0%    10   59.0  65.8  57.7  84.4   8.9----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }

   9.|-- 216.58.199.174  0.0%    10   55.0  63.7  53.9  79.8   9.5----{ United States }----{ Mountain View }

Done
```

This output is mixed *mtr* lines from all threads. I want output in the sequential order without any mixups. Please help guide me to come out of this problem. I am new to python and trying hard to learn it.

Comment: Locks wouldn't solve your problem anyway. Probably the only solution is to temporarily collect the output from all the threads and then when they're all done, sort it into the proper order before displaying it. Such is the nature of concurrent processing.

Comment: MTR is a mixture of ping & traceroute. It is used to check any latency or packet loss in the network. It is a unix package. we run it like "mtr <IP>" and it will show every hop in the way with packet loss and latency statistics.

Comment: martineau: Can you please elaborate with code.